# Google Maps API KML Layer Stopped Working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

This is my code which was working fine for the last couple months up until yesterday my KML Layer just stopped working. I did not change anything in my code so I'm wondering if it is something to do with a limited number of calls per month or if there is a bug on google's end. I ran my file through a KML validator just to make sure and it was good. Thanks for any help!

```
<div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>

        <script>

            function initMap() {

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: {lat: 30.831048, lng: -83.278934}
                });

                var src = 'http://mysgmcbenefits.com/forms/ga_counties_20.kml';

                var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                    preserveViewport: false,
                    map: map
                });



            }

        </script>


    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <small><i>*Records based on zip code of patient’s residence.</i></small>    
    </div>

</div>


<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=;)">
</script>
```

Comment: also, the actual map and markers all still work fine, it is just the KML layer

Comment: Please provide a (tested/working) [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  [The KmlLayer by itself works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fekgyncw/8/) (when I remove or fix the problems with the posted code).

Comment: The fiddle you posted does not work for me. I still see no KML Layer. I updated the post to be a testable version

Comment: That implies a location/server dependency.  What is the KmlStatus on the fiddle (the string above the map)? Perhaps a corrupt version of your KML got cached.

Comment: The KML status is "FETCH_ERROR". I thought the same thing so I tried changing the KML file name and updating the link in my code before I made this post but that didn't fix it either.